# Best approach to speed up pixel processing in matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, image-processing

I have a couple of big 3 dimensional matrices (e.g. dimension:16330,1300,16). For each cell I need to develop a simple linear regression model and extract some information such as slope and intercept of the fitted model.I created a loop and run the processing pixel by pixel but it will take for ever. Is there any suggestion that I can improve the following code?

```
% read the multiband image (16330,1300,16)
[A,R] = geotiffread('16Bands_image.tif'); 

% this is a vector (1*16) that i fit it against the third dimension of each 
%pixel throughout the image
Load external.m 

intercept = zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2));
slope = zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2));

for i=1:size(A,1)
   for j=1:size(A,2)
     REF=squeeze(A(i,j,:));
     p=fitlm(REF,external);
     intercept(i,j)=p.Coefficients.Estimate(1);
     slope(i,j) = p.Coefficients.Estimate(2);
   end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: If p = fitlm(external, REF) is good for you, there is a simple and fast solution. That is to reshape A to 16 by N, then b = [ones(16,1) external(:)] \ A;. row 1 and 2 of b are intercept and slope. You can then reshape b into image dimension.

Comment: What version of matlab do you have?

Comment: My version is R2017b. I'm trying @XiangruiLi solution right now, see if vectorization works....

Comment: @XiangruiLi Thanks for the solution and it works, the thing is I'm interested in p = fitlm( REF, external) not p = fitlm(external, REF) . May I ask then how can use the \ operator for this setup. Thanks again

Comment: Then  I don't realize a way to avoid "for" loop over pixels. You can still replace fitlm with \ operator, which will speed up considerably, but it is still slow since you have so many pixels.

Comment: Yeah, \ helped a lot and reduced my calculations from many hours to a couple of minutes! and thats good enough for me. I think my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  p = fitlm(external, REF) is what you need, there is a fast solution: reshape the image into 16 by (16330*1300), and apply the model without loop.

```
A = reshape(A, [], 16)'; % reshape and transpose to 16 by N

X = external(:);
X = X - mean(X);
b = [ones(16,1) X] \ A; % solve all once
```

Rows 1 and 2 of b are intercept and slope respectively.

I don't know your data, but this supposes A is the measured data.

If indeed you want the other way, you may still need loop over pixels:

```
external = external(:); % make sure it is column
b = zeros(2, size(A,2)); % A in 16 by N
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    X = A(:,i);
    X = X - mean(X);
    b(:,i) = [ones(16,1) X] \ external; 
end
```

But this is still slow, although it is faster than fitlm.